GnuCash: Non-Exact Exchange Rates
GnuCash ver. 3.4
GnuCash does not appear to be using the exact exchange rate that I've input manually.
For example:
I manually enter (via the Price Database tool) an exchange rate of 0.67 U.S. Dollars per 1.00 Andorran Franc.
I then generate a Profit & Loss report, with the "Show Exchange Rates" report option selected.
A look at the end of said report shows that an exchange rate of "₣1.00  $0.67002" is being utilized.
Is there any way to correct this inaccuracy? Is this a bug? If so, has it been corrected yet?

Would the converted values in your report be different if you used the exact exchange rate?

@DStanley Not sure what's being asked, but I've seen converted amounts on the referenced report be off by more than a dollar...

My two completely uneducated guesses would be:

The exchange rate in internally re-calculated as an "Andorran Franc to US Dollar" rate (it's not uncommon for the Dollar to be used as an "anchor" currency for doing FX calculations).  If I take the reciprocal rate (1.4925373134), round it to 4 decimals (1.4925) and take the reciprocal again,. I get 0.67002. That may just be coincidence, but it demonstrates that rounding anywhere in the process can have an effect when dealing with floating-point data.

The exchange rate is back-calculated using the results of some aggregate values (e.g. your total Profit) that involves some rounding, leaving you with a slightly different exchange rate.


However, does it make a material difference? If you calculated your PnL using the exact rate would it come our any differently? My guess is that the extra 0.00002 in the rate is lost in the converted values that are rounded to 2 or 4 decimal places, and that your report totals would not be materially different.

The biggest errors I've seen amount to about a dollar or so...I was just wondering if there was something I could do to prevent these admittedly small errors.

I tried a "dummy" exchange rate of 0.80. The value that was displayed on the subject report was exactly 0.80...

The exchange rates are represented as float or double types, which may lead to precision issues.

This would be a good candidate for the accepted answer if you were able to provide at least one good reference wrt how GnuCash performs these calculations...

I'd need to dig into the code, I've always wanted and never had the time... I've seen the tool convert the values into fractions, which led me to the conclusion that it's a float precision error.

−1: Finance arithmetics are done in ℤ, exactly because of such freak issues. In the case of GNUCash, all operations are done in the wrapper class GncNumeric, which accepts GncRational, which uses GncInt128 so you have your integral operations in the end, too.

Thanks for the pointers, I'll take a look
